# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'wait'

Tags: ос, python-3.8

```
import subprocess import os

# Функция для запуска скрипта 2 из скрипта 1
def run_script2():
    script2_process = subprocess.Popen(["python", "script2.py"])
    return script2_process

# Основной код "скрипта 1"
# Здесь может быть любая логика, которая в конечном итоге завершится

script2_process = run_script2()

# Ожидание завершения "скрипта 1"
# При завершении "скрипта 1" принудительно завершаем все порожденные процессы, включая скрипт 2 
try:
    os.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("KeyboardInterrupt: Terminating all spawned scripts.")
    script2_process.terminate()
```

При запуске данного кода у меня почему то вылезает ошибка:

> **AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'wait'**

Я не понимаю, что не так. В документации эта функция есть, написано верно, а версия **python 3.8.3**.

Кто понимает, в чем проблема, можете помочь с этим?

Comment: Хм, а у меня этот код вообще `OSError` выдает. Непонятно, наверное, какие-то конфликты внутри питона.

Comment: [«Availability: Unix»](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.wait) — а вы уверены, что у вас Unix?